# iPhone Photos Geolocation Displayed in Wrong Language

Tags: iphone, photos.app, internationalization, language

My phone language has almost always been set to English and I've always had my geolocation on for my pictures. A couple of months ago I rearranged the ***Preferred Language Order*** to bring **Persian** to the top, over **English**, to check something in an app. Then I reverted it to the previous order, English on top.

Note that there's a difference between ***iPhone Language*** and ***Preferred Language Order*** and Persian is NOT among the supported languages for iPhone Language; I can only add it to the locale list (Preferred Language Order) and if I move it to the top, it'll adapt the locale for the apps that do support it.

Since I did this, the *Photos* app switched all my previous geolocation tags to **Arabic** (which is the closest supported language to Persian!)

How can I fix this so that the names appear in English again while the phone language is set to English and those photos were taken in an English speaking country long before I'd changed the language?

[image: Photos.app Locale]

I've tried rebooting the phone as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7584208) but that did not help. I've also completely removed Persian from the Preferred Language Order list, and nothing has changed.

[image: Photos.app Wrong Locale]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months of back and forth with Apple Support, and they've been as useless as they could over the matter. Every time I've followed they've asked for a few extra screenshots and then once I've submitted them, they've gone silent and unresponsive.

After spending lots of time on this, I managed to fix my problem. Here's what I tried, what did not work and what eventually worked:

I tried switching the phone language several times to many different latin and non latin languages, and that did nothing. I also tried taking photos while the language was switched and it was saving them with the new language, but after reverting to English, those old tags were remaining in Arabic.

So here is what worked (and it was not so complicated to my surprise!):

Go to Settings app > General > Reset > Reset All Settings

Note that this doest NOT delete any media or data. All it does is resetting all phone settings like wallpapers, ringtones, etc. to default, without any data loss.
[image: after resetting]